# Get values by condition from different column and index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given df that represent an events of users.

```
index   id  action_id   feature session_id  n_page duration
1       1    null       null    1_1         1      1
2       1    3          a       1_1         2      1
3       1    null               1_1         3      1
4       1    null       pay     1_1         4      1
5       1    24                 1_1         5      1
6       1    107                1_1         6      2
7       2    null               2_1         1      1
8       2    107        c       2_1         2      1
9       2    null               2_1         3      1
10      2    34         pay     2_1         4      1
```

I need to group by session_id and get the  last values of the  feature column when the action id == 3 or 107 only in session that has action_id == 34 or 24 and the n_page value by action_id

Output df:

```
session_id  n_page  feature sum_duration
1_1         5       a       7
2_1         4       c       4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_group = df[["session_id", "sum_duration"]].groupby("session_id")["sum_duration"].sum().reset_index()

df_dup = df[(df["action_id"] == 3)| (df["action_id"] == 104)]["session_id","n_page","feature"]

df_dup.merge(df_group, on = "session_id", how = "inner" )
```

We can change joining condition based on the desired output.
If this does not produce the desired output, it would be great if you provide the code used to create input data.

Comment: There is more aggregations on the df, thats the reason that i need to groupby .

Comment: @MPA output you mentioned does not show what you are looking for. In this output, no aggregation is done on any feature.

Comment: That's what i did finally, I thought there is a better solution.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Filter rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and join together by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df['action_id'].isin([3,107]),["session_id","feature"]]
df2 = df.loc[df['action_id'].isin([34,24]),["session_id","n_page"]]

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='session_id')
print (df3)
  session_id feature  n_page
0        1_1       a       5
1        2_1       c       4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. Hope this will help.

First perform grouping if you have large dataset.

```
grouped_df = data_df.groupby('id')
```

Now get the grouped df from group by object of grouped_df

```
grouped_df.get_group(1)[ (grouped_df.get_group(1)['action_id'] == 3) | (grouped_df.get_group(1)['action_id'] == 107)  ]
```

Instead of 1 in the get_group function, you can use the desired key value, to get the desired group.

Comment: Yes @jezrael i have tested it.

Comment: Super, so always the best add output data to answer (from input data).